# Confused about increment with ++

Tags: c

I want to increment a variable so c is 4 and d is c ++ (so is 5)

This code works

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int c = 4;
int d = ++c ;
printf("Value of c is: %d \n", c);
printf("Value of d is: %d \n", d);
}
```

The problem is that return 5 for c and d.

```
Value of c is: 5 
Value of d is: 5
```

I want to obtain this:

```
Value of c is: 4
Value of d is: 5
```

My idea is to declare a var (c) assign 4 to c, then
declare d and assign value of c ++ to d.
Something like this on bash but using ++ and not +1 (is too easy)

```
#!/bin/bash
c=4

echo "C is now $c"

d=$((++c))

echo "D is now $d"
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: `int d = c + 1;`

Comment: Too easy, I want to know if is possible to use ++ for increment the same variable, or if work only on for and while cycles.

Comment: `++` is modifying it's operand value, but you say you don't want it.

Comment: Is not possible to increment using ++? I have used it  in for and while cycle

Comment: `++` is incrementing it's operand. But here you want the incremented value to go into another variable.

Comment: `int d = (++c)--;` :)

Comment: `c++` and `++c` will always change the value of `c`.  Left side, right side, in an if.  War never changes but `c` always does.

Comment: @IłyaBursov Looks like UB to me...

Comment: @EugeneSh. yeah, probably, but it works in some online compilers

Comment: The whole point of `++` and `--` operators is that they modify the operand. If you don't want to modify the operand, don't use them.

Comment: There's no shortcut for `variable+1`.

Comment: To "increment" a variable means to *modify its value* by adding to it.  You cannot use either version of the autoincrement operator (`++`) without modifying the value of the object that is its operand.  **That's what it does.**  You can reverse the increment after the fact, of course, but that's a much worse strategy than not modifying the value at all.

Comment: *"I want to know if is possible to use ++ for increment the same variable"* please elaborate on that. If you are trying to solve an homework question, please post the exact problem statement.

Comment: @IłyaBursov: that should throw up a diagnostic since the result of an `++` or `--` expression is not an lvalue; any compiler that accepts that code is broken.  That's not UB, that's a straight-up constraint violation and a diagnostic is required.

Comment: I really wish `(++c)--` worked, not for any practical reason but just to see if I could get it past code review.

Comment: @JohnBode from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec) `the prefix increment or decrement is an lvalue expression that identifies the modified operand.` so it is lvalue, thus postfix can be applied to it

Comment: @JohnBode but, it is not lvalue in C apparently

Comment: @IłyaBursov that site also have the C documentation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_incdec , in particular, the notes part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try and break it down. First off, you need to understand how operators work (lucky for you, the way they work in C is the same as in C++, C#, D, java and many similar languages so it's actually a very useful lesson). You also need to understand what `++` (or `--`) do as opposed to `+1` (or `-1`) and where you need to use each. So before you read on, please, "pause" this answer and do some reading on C operators (yes, **ALL** of them, trust me, there is no such thing as "I won't need *that* one"... or better said, there is no such thing as "I won't need *that* one" if you want to learn how to write code, regardless of the language).

If you finished your little "external" lesson, by now you should have the following info:

```c
void func()
{
    int c = 1;
    int d = 2;
    int e = c + 1;
}
```

And you should know `c` is 1, `d` is 2 and `e` is 2 as well.

But let's try some pre* and post* operators.

```c
void func()
{
    int c = 1;
    int d = 2;
    int e = c + 1;
    int f = d + 2;
    int g = d + 2;
    ++f;
    g++;
}
```

Here, you have `c` is 1, `d` is 2 and `e` is 2, f is 5 (first it was 4, then it was incremented once), g is 5 as well (same idea). But wait, isn't it the same? "Yes" and No (mostly No, hence the quotations in "Yes").

```c
void func()
{
    int c = 1;
    int d = 2;
    int e = c + 1;
    int f = ++d + 2;
}
```

`c` is 1, first `d` is 2 and `e` is 2, `f` is 5, but `d` becomes 3. Why? Because unlike `+` which is a standard maths operation (the basic `1 + 1 = 2`), `++` also modifies the value of the variable (or parameter, depending on the case).

The difference in speech would be:

1. `c + 1`: If you were to add 1 to your value, what would be the result? (the initial value is unchanged, but the result is different)
2. `c++`: If you were to increment your value, what would be the result? (the initial value is changed, because it is incremented, it's manipulated)

In other words, use `++` and `--` only if you want the value of that var (or param) to change as well. So you might ask "ok, fine, normally, I will have vars or params with the values I need, so why would I want to change those values in such a way that it might mess up my code?". Well, it depends on the workflow, but in most cases, `++` and `--` is used in iterations. That is not their sole usage, but it is the most common one.

But your other curiosity might be "OK, fine, but when to use `++x` and when to use `x++`?". The answer is "it depends". In `for` loops, it won't matter. In `do-while`, it might. The difference between pre* and post* operators is that in the case of a pre-operator the value is changed first, then the value is used, while in post-operators the *current* value is used, and *then* it is changed.

But let me give you an example from a project of mine. Unfortunately it's in C# (so excuse the spaghetti), but as discussed earlier, the logic is the same:

```c-sharp
public Texture GetNextAnimationFrame(ref uint currentSequence)
{
    if (m_Frames.Length == 1)
        return m_Frames[0];

    if (currentSequence >= m_Frames.Length)
        currentSequence = 0;

    return m_Frames[currentSequence ++];
}
```

It's basically an array of a limited number of frames, it advances each frame to give the illusion of a "movie", then when it reaches the end, it resets to the first frame and loops over and over. But let's focus on our topic: `return m_Frames[currentSequence ++];`

What is the difference between `m_Frames[currentSequence++]` and `m_Frames[++currentSequence]`?

In the case of `currentSequence++` I basically tell the code "get the array `m_Frames`, use the element with the id that is the value of `currentSequence`, then after you `return` it, increment it by 1, so that the next time we loop, we have the next frame in our *movie*".

If I were to use `++currentSequence`, then the sequence would be desynced, because it would first increment (always skipping the *first* frame) and then use the frame and loop, because it would first change the value, then use its value, which is not what I wanted).

And this is what happens to your `int d = ++c ;`.

Hope I managed to explain the jist of it :)

Of course, as others already pointed out and as you probably figured out by now, in order to get the values you want, you need to do `int d = c + 1;` in order to **NOT** change the value of `c`.

Comment: Perfect answer I will vote as solution, thanks.

Comment: _"the way they work in C is the same as in C++, C#, D, java and many similar languages"_ -- be careful with this. `++` can and does have different semantics even in other C-like languages, e.g., it may be overloaded in C++, Go does not even have pre-increment, only post-increment, undefined behavior may be delineated differently in different C-like languages, etc.

Comment: I know, but I didn't want to overcomplicate things with overloading. There are many moments I saw game engines using `*` and `^` for `Dot` and `Cross` in Vector `struct`s (or `class`es), thus confusing even more the issue of "is `*` a pointer or is it `&`? and what is the difference?" I have a feeling it will be a long time before the OP reaches operator overloading. And while I do agree, I wouldn't it add it now, but I think your comment should cover most *if*s and other caveats.

Answer (score 5):

If you *do not* want to change the value of `c`, then you cannot use the `++` operator on it:

```
Expression    Value of c   Value of d
----------    ----------   ----------
   d = c++             5            4
   d = ++c             5            5
 d = c + 1             4            5
```

The `++` and `--` operators have both a *result* and a *side effect*:

```
Expression        Result                  Side effect
----------        ------                  -----------
       x++        Current value of x      x <- x + 1
       ++x        Current value of x + 1  x <- x + 1
       x--        Current value of x      x <- x - 1
       --x        Current value of x - 1  x <- x - 1
```

The operators *will* modify the value stored in the operand.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is "no". `++c` always has the side effect of updating `c` to the incremented value.

When using the value of the expression, the only choice is whether to return the original value (with post-increment `c++`) or the updated value (with pre-increment `++c`).

To get the incremented value without updating the variable, use `c + 1`. There's no shortcut for this.

Comment: Not that `++c` is much of a shortcut relative to `c + 1`.

Comment: Indeed, if you leave out the spaces they're the same length. But `++` is still conceptually a shortcut, because you've replaced an explicit parameter `1` with syntax that compactly expresses the notion of "increment"

Comment: @JohnBollinger With the exception that `+1` keeps the initial value unchanged while `++` also changes the initial value. This is where the OP had problems understanding the code flow. @Barmar I don't think the OP knew the difference between *adding* and *incrementing* which is why I tried to break it down.

Comment: @TheNomad I think John's comment is simply reacting to my reference to "shortcut", since it's not really much shorter.

Comment: No explanation needed from your side, I won't discuss the knowledge of either of you, I just wanted to point it out mostly for the OP, since they are new. To be fair, when I first started C I had no idea what is the difference between pre* and post* ops and while *technically* a pre-operator is "faster", I didn't understand why it messed up `while{}` loops and would argue with team members how my pre-op code is "better". This question brings back memories of being a noob myself back in the days not completely understanding it all :) -> not that I am a C++ grandmaster now but you get the point.

Comment: The most common misunderstanding shows up as `c = c++`

Comment: I C what you did there!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the ++ increment operator to achieve this in the way you suggest. ++ changes the value of the variable.

```
int c = 4;
int d = ++c ;
```

Now c is 5 and d is also 5, because c is incremented first, then returned to the assignment operator.

```
int c = 4;
int d = c++;
```

Now d is 4 and c is 5, because c is first returned to the assignment operator, then incremented.

What the OP asks for is that

```
int c = 4;
int d = [some ++ usage on c];
```

so that d is 5 and c remains 4. This cannot be done with ++. It can be done with the good old + operator:

```
int c = 4;
int d = c + 1;
```

++ will change c, either before or after the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround found:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int c = 4;

printf("Value of c is: %d \n", c);

int d = ++c ;

printf("Value of d is: %d \n", d);
}
```

return:

```
Value of c is: 4 
Value of d is: 5
```

Comment: Might wanna print the values of both `c` and `d` in that second print statement.

Comment: This _prints_ "Value of c is: 4", but the value of `c` is _not_ 4 after `d` is initialized.

Comment: Note well that the final value of `c` is still 5 here. The printed output just reports on a previous value of `c`.  If that's what you really wanted then the question does a poor job of conveying it.

Comment: I want this, increment by 1 a value

Comment: You said: `I want to obtain this: Value of c is: 4`, it did display c = 4, but the value of c is 5 before the app exits. So the question is, did you want to achieve the text to display or the value? There is a big difference and I think you need to study a little more in order to understand the difference. In a normal application environment, your code would be wrong and would mess up the workflow of the application completely and trust me, it would be hell to debug it, if it was complex enough (i.e. enterprise level).

Comment: Not an answer for the question you asked.  `c` is 5 after the statement that still changes it.  Either the question wording is wrong or your solution is.

Answer (score -1):

```
int main()
{
    int c = 4;
    int d = c;

    d = c++,c;

    printf("Value of c is: %d \n", c);
    printf("Value of d is: %d \n", d);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/3ojv7enW6

or to get it right

```
int main()
{
    int c = 4;
    int d = c;

    c = d++;

    printf("Value of c is: %d \n", c);
    printf("Value of d is: %d \n", d);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/h3bnMva6M

Comment: This is the opposite of what they want.

Comment: Thanks, but return the inverse, Value of c is: 5 
Value of d is: 4, is possible to fix replacing c with d but is not correct

Comment: @Barmar but it is only what they can get not changing more significantly the code.

Comment: No way to use ++ so?

Comment: In the second snippet `c = d++;` can be just `d++;`

Comment: Using the last code works, waiting for a best answer i vote this

Comment: The best answer was given in the first comment by @Ilya

Comment: No, because  + 1  is ok, but I want ++, if is possible

Comment: @elbarna -- why do you want to use `++`? This is the wrong construct for this purpose.

Comment: Only for see if works